# Array filter elements that are too close to each other's value

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have the following

```
    var dates = [
        "2017-09-11 13:30:45", 
        "2017-09-11 14:20:00", 
        "2017-09-11 15:00:00"
        ]
```

I want to remove the middle date because it's too close to the previous one (less than one hour). Once removed, the third should stay there because it's not too close to the previous one (which would be the first one now)

I know how to convert the date and I know how to make a basic for loop to find which date to remove and I know how to remove it.

My question is: Is there any one liner that could solve this for me ? I was looking through lodash but couldn't find any

Clarifications:

The array is always sorted. The function should verify the current element against the previous one. If the current one is removed, the next element should be compared to the same element as the one removed

Comment: Please provide more information. Is the array always sorted? What are your criteria for filtering? What should happen, if value a is too close to b and b is too close to c, but a would be not close enough to c, when b is removed?

Comment: @iquellis updated my question

Comment: Speaking like a product manager, I would guess that "the next element should be compared to the same element as the one removed" is maybe not what you want? However, the solutions provided below should work.

Comment: @iquellis that is what I want, if the element is removed. after that iteration it should move along. I know I may not make sense, but I don't know how to explain better

Comment: hahaha, okay :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a *one-liner*, but it's not long:

```
let lastDate = null;
dates = dates.filter(date => {
  date = parseDate(date);
  if (!lastDate || date - lastDate >= ONE_HOUR) {
    lastDate = date;
    return true;
  }
});
```

```js
let dates = [
    "2017-09-11 13:30:45", 
    "2017-09-11 14:20:00", 
    "2017-09-11 15:00:00"
    ];
const ONE_HOUR = 1000 * 60 * 60;
let lastDate = null;
dates = dates.filter(date => {
  date = parseDate(date);
  if (!lastDate || date - lastDate >= ONE_HOUR) {
    lastDate = date;
    return true;
  }
});
console.log(dates);

function parseDate(s) {
  return Date.parse(s.replace(' ', 'T'));
}
```

Comment: Ack! Missed out a bit of the `if`. Fixed now. Technically it worked fine without the guard, because the result of `date - lastDate` coerced the `null` in `lastDate` to `0` and so returned the full milliseconds-since-the-Epoch value of `date`, which is `>= ONE_HOUR`. But probably not ideal to rely on it.

Answer (score 4):

One-liner, probably not, but you can do something like this:

```
var last = -Infinity, threshold = 60 * 60 * 1000;
var result = dates.filter(function(date) {
    var time = Date.parse(date);
    if( time - last < threshold) return false;
    last = time;
    return true;
});
```

This keeps track of the previous timestamp, allowing the `filter` call to reference it.

Comment: LOL, very similar to what I was doing simultaneously. But best not to rely on `Date.parse` to parse those dates, as it's unspecified behavior.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I believe `Date.parse` is safe to use on `Y-m-d H:i:s` format strings since it's ISO-8601 (minus the `T`)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder But doesn't your code use `Date.parse` just you call it in another function? Or do you mean just not to use it with the format it's currently in?

Comment: @Matt: Look more closely at my `parseDate`.

Comment: @Matt T.J. replaces the space with a T to make it closer to ISO-8601, although to be accurate it should have `+'Z'` at the end ;)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: No, the behavior is unspecified without the T: https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: No, the `Z` is optional. It means "local time" (with these strings; if they were date-only, it would be UTC).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder For that I asked about just not with the format it's currently in. Meaning to not use parseDate at all or to modify the string prior to using it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Consider me corrected. But while `Y-m-d H:i:s` is "unspecified", it's at least unambiguous and handled consistently :)

Comment: @Matt: Ah, I didn't see the edit until after replying. Yes, just not on the format in the qusetion.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: I wouldn't be at all surprised if it's *not* handled consistently (e.g., that some JavaScript engines treat it as UTC, and others as local time). Fortunately, though, that doesn't really matter here (hmmm, or might it, at a DST boundary?). In any case, anyone coming to this is sufficiently warned! :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want more control later, you can use a more popular `date time` parsing library like `moment.js`. It will make your code much more ***readable*** and ***maintainable***.

```js
var dates = [
  "2017-09-11 13:30:45",
  "2017-09-11 14:20:00",
  "2017-09-11 15:00:00"
];

var TIME_DIFF = 45; //minutes

for (var i = 0; i < dates.length - 1; i++) {
  if (Math.abs(moment(dates[i + 1]).diff(moment(dates[i]), 'minutes')) > TIME_DIFF) {
    dates.splice(i + 1, 1);
  }
}

console.log(dates);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.js"></script>
```

More details can be found here.
https://momentjs.com/